# Facing problem in Exporting a ipynb file to pdf in VS Code

Tags: python, pdf, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have fulfilled all the requirements for exporting a jupyter notebook (ipynb) to pdf in VScode but still, it gives me the same error of installing TeX, Although

I have MiKTex installed in my system
I have Installed TeX package
I have Pandoc installed in my system.

When I installed MiKTeX and TeX it was not working but when I installed Pandoc it just worked once but now it giving me the same error.

This is how I have installed the dependencies:

- I have installed `nbconvert` through this command `pip install nbconvert`.
- For TeX `pip install tex`
- For `pandoc` i downloaded an `.exe` file from their website and installed it in my system, besides this I also installed pandoc package through this command in terminal `pip install pandoc`

However I still have an error:

> error 13:11:2.772: If you have not installed xelatex (TeX) you will
> need to do so before you can export to PDF, for further instructions
> please look
> nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex. To
> avoid installing xelatex (TeX) you might want to try exporting to HTML
> and using your browsers "Print to PDF" feature.

Kindly Help me in this regard TIA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Export Jupyter Notebook by VSCode in PDF format? (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049818/how-to-export-jupyter-notebook-by-vscode-in-pdf-format-windows-10)

Answer (score 4):

Open the jupyter file with Chrome and convert it to PDF by printing. This way is simpler and more effective.

---

#### UPDATE:

- First make sure that the `path` environment variable of **Tex** already exists in your machine

  [image]
- Then run vscode with **admin**

  [image]
- Use the following command in the terminal (or the terminal where the virtual environment is activated if using a virtual environment) to export the PDF

  ```
  # Remember to replace your_notebook with your filename
  jupyter nbconvert your_notebook.ipynb --to pdf
  ```

  [image]

  *During the execution of the command, many such pop-up windows may pop up prompting you to install files, please select "Install"*

  [image]

  *Sorry for the Chinese interface*
- After the command is executed, a PDF file will be generated in the same directory as your jupyter file.

  [image]

**After that you can run vscode without administrator and export PDF. Also, the interfaced export can also be used.**

[image]

Comment: jupyter: The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

When i run the above mentioned command in terminal. it gives that error.

Comment: Install and add an environment variable (`path`) to it. It can be installed via [conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/). Or try installing with the command `pip install notebook`.

Answer (score 1):

The installation of MiKTeX and TeX depends on the operating system.

If you are using Linux try executing the following code inside the terminal of your environment:

```
apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic
```

If you are using Windows you should get the MiKTeX exe [here](https://miktex.org/download) and install it following the wizard. The installation is really simple (just follow the wizard), but if you need to, you can check out the official [instructions](https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex).

Also refer to this [link](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-nbconvert) for full instructions to install the additional packages that may be needed by `nbconvert`.

Comment: I have installed all the additional packages needed by nbcovert plus MiKTeX the same way instructed on the mentioned links. but still it giving there ERROR mentioned above.