# How to set up Latex in VS Code for Jupyter Notebook (Windows)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, latex

I have started learning Python and I want to record my sessions through Jupyter Notebooks used in VS Code, as well as to export them to PDF. However, I am unable to do so because it requires Latex and it does not seem to be so easy to install as a regular library such as numpy.

I get the following message when exporting to PDF via VS interface:

```
[error] If you have not installed xelatex (TeX) you will need to do so before you can export to PDF, for further instructions please look https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex.To avoid installing xelatex (TeX) you might want to try exporting to HTML and using your browsers "Print to PDF" feature.
```

It also says I'm missing Pandoc although I have installed it **via pip**. (I believe this has to do with not having TeX). I have checked the link that shows up, but I don't know how to set up Latex in Windows. I have installed MikTex, and a couple extensions in VS (Latex and Latex Workshop). How can  I install it successfully to be able to export to PDF?

When I open Miktex packages, I just get an empty console.

Also, I have used Latex online with Overleaf, and every time I wanted to include a package, I just used \includepackage{...}. Would this work  in the same way in VS? Since it's not online I'm not sure if it would be that easy to download packages.

Comment: It is more convenient to open the jupyter file in the browser and use the print function to export to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to install Pandoc not from pip but from the official site, and then **add its location to PATH**. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct tex library installed?

Please follow the step according to [the document](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex).

If you are using windows, you can download [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/).

If you are familiar with Git you can also clone the repository using the command line or your favorite Git fontend tool:

```
git clone  https://github.com/latex3/latex2e.git
```

Answer (score 0):

> To avoid installing xelatex (TeX) you might want to try exporting to HTML and using your browsers "Print to PDF" feature.

- select html when exporting

  [image]
- Open the exported `name.html` file with a browser
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the printed page, use `Print to PDF` to export it as a pdf file

If you still want to export to pdf directly in vscode, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73469534/facing-problem-in-exporting-a-ipynb-file-to-pdf-in-vs-code/73470335#73470335), there are detailed steps.

Comment: When I make jupyter export the notebook, it says I don't have pandoc. But it's actually there when I use pip install pandoc! Why?

Comment: Edit your question to show the detailed error and your operation steps etc.