# Convert ipynb to txt or markdown file format

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to convert ipynb file into txt or a markdown file where the JSON of the notebook file is wrapped in a code block?

I have a file ipynb which i want to convert into markdown or plain txt file. I create the file using vscode IDE. I don't see export to txt or md option. I have jupyter extension installed in vscode.

Comment: You can export your file as html (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049818/how-to-export-jupyter-notebook-by-vscode-in-pdf-format-windows-10), then convert html to markdown with a HTML2MD converter

Comment: @starball Yes I mean JSON wrapped in a code block

Comment: With [Jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats-markdown.html#jupytext-markdown) you can convert it to markdown that can be run still like a notebook and converted back, see the last command in the first code block of [this section here in the documentation](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html#execute-notebook-cells).

Answer (score 1):

You can view the textual JSON contents of Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code by using the `View: Reopen Editor With Text Editor` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). If you want to create a markdown file containing that JSON wrapped in a code block, the just select all the JSON contents from the text view, then create a markdown file with a code block, and paste the contents of the file into that code block.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, go to the directory with the notebook, and run

```bash
python -m notebook
```

It will open a page in a browser. Open your notebook. Under `File` in the top left, you can export your notebook into various formats.

Comment: WOW. I learned something new. Thank you so much. And this is so much helpful.

Comment: I am glad. Don't forget to add checkmark to the answer then ;)

Answer (score 1):

One better solution:
Jupyter notebook has more options to export, also markdown and plain text.

[image]

Comment: If you have installed Jupyter then you can do all the same exporting from the command line using `jupyter nbconvert` because under the hood that is what the Jupyter GUI that is shown in this answer is using. (Jupytext that I mentioned in my comment adds an easier interface to this sort of thing.) That way the OP is not needing to open a second IDE. The OP would though need Jupyter installed. (Related: The OP mentions using VSCode but not if they have installed the plugin/extension to work with Jupyter? I cannot speak to what if any conversion options it adds. Maybe someone knows?)

Answer (score 0):

Open your ipynb file with `Text Editor` in Linux or with `Notepad` in Windows.
Then you will see a json like file. You can save it as txt file.

Comment: I don't have Linux or Windows. I'm using Macbook Air.

Comment: @NafiRahim macOS has Text Editor too.