# How can I capture all cells and outputs from Jupyter in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, capture

I'm working with Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code, and I'm looking for a way to capture all the cells and their outputs in a single document or format for documentation and sharing. Is there a method or extension that can help with this?

Specifically, I'd like to:

1)Capture the code cells.
2)Capture the corresponding output of each code cell (including text, images, plots, etc.).
3)Ideally, organize these captures into a single document or file.

I've heard about the "Codesnap" extension, but I'm not sure how to use it for this purpose. Can someone provide guidance on using "Codesnap" effectively for this task?

Expected Output:
I'm looking for suggestions, guidance, or code examples on how to capture all cells and their outputs in a Jupyter notebook within Visual Studio Code, and specifically, how to use the "Codesnap" extension for this.

Steps Taken:
I've explored Jupyter and the "Codesnap" extension, but I haven't been able to figure out how to capture all cells and outputs comprehensively.

Programming Language and Environment:

Programming Language: Python
Environment: Visual Studio Code
Jupyter extension installed in VS Code
Dependencies and Versions:

Visual Studio Code
Jupyter extension for VS Code
"Codesnap" extension

Comment: You can use File -> Download As and save the notebook as a PDF.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @TimRoberts where does that feature come from? What VS Code Extension? Or are you referring to another application for working with Jupyter Notebooks?

Comment: I skipped right over the VSCode part.  You can use Export, but you'd need to have TeX installed.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#:~:text=You%20can%20export%20a%20Jupyter,you%20must%20have%20TeX%20installed.

Comment: Also look over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049818/how-to-export-jupyter-notebook-by-vscode-in-pdf-format-windows-10, although none of the solutions seems perfect.

Comment: I export it as html file and then printed it,.....Anyway thanks for the comments

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

In vscode, you can click `Export` to export Jupyter as the type of file you want.

[image]

[image]

*If export is PDF, you may need to install some other things.
[Facing problem in Exporting a ipynb file to pdf in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73469534/facing-problem-in-exporting-a-ipynb-file-to-pdf-in-vs-code/73470335#73470335)*